# Adding multiple evaluation expression in For Loop SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

Is it possible to add multiple evaluation expression in for loop container.

Background:
I have a file, in the file the value of a field will be Y/N, If the value is N then I have to keep reading this file until the value is Y then exit for loop.

To do this, I used a for loop inside for loop I am loading the data into record set destination and assigning the values to a variable called "@Value"
Now in for loop I am keeping this condition

```
Init : @Start = 0
Eval : @Value = "N"
Assi : @Start = @Start + 1
```

Now I have to add one more condition in for loop such that, it has iterate only 5 times then exit.
so I used @Value == "N" || @Start > 10 in evaluation expression. But it is not working. OR part is not considering, How can I achieve it.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a Boolean variable with `Evaluate as expression = true` with your conditions and substituting the For-Loop Eval with this variable?

Comment: BTW, the `Eval` test with the Boolean variable would be `@BooTest= "True"` (assuming your evaluated variable is called Bootest)

Comment: The problem is I have to add one more condition in Eval Expression. like '@Value == "N" || @Start > 10' Can that be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm simply suggesting an alternate way of achieving the same result! :-)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, created variable and wrote an expression to handle these 2 conditions.